# How many seconds from midnight until specific Datetime

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp

Is there a nice simple shorthand way of finding out how many seconds past midnight a certain datetime is? Not how many seconds it is away from now, the seconds past in that day

eg:

- `2015-04-10 00:00:00` should returns `0`
- `2015-04-12 09:20:00` should returns `33600`
- `2015-04-14 15:20:00` should returns `55200`

Is there a nice short method of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you just extract hours, minutes and seconds and calculate (hours*60+minutes)*60+seconds? Or what format exactly is your timestamp in?

Comment: It's in the format shown. My original method was to do something like mktime(0,0,0,strtotime(date('m',$stamp)),strtotime(date('d',$stamp)),strtotime(date('Y',$stamp))) - but I was wondering if there's a shorthand version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code for you.

Any day code

```
<?php
$date = "2015-04-12 09:20:00";

$midnight = strtotime(date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($date)));
$now = strtotime($date);

$diff = $now - $midnight;
echo $diff;
?>
```

Current day code

```
<?php
$midnight = strtotime("midnight");
$now = date('U');

$diff = $now - $midnight;
echo $diff;
?>
```

Maybe a more clean code would be to use `strtotime("midnight", <EpochTime>);`

```
<?php
$date = "2015-04-12 09:20:00";

$midnight = strtotime("midnight", strtotime($date));
$now = strtotime($date);

$diff = $now - $midnight;
echo $diff;
?>
```

Comment: I've re-accepted this as the answer for any future users as it's probably closer to the method I've used

Answer (score 1):

A day is 24 hours is 60 minutes is 60 seconds is 1000 miliseconds, so timestamp % (24*60*60*1000) could work, maybe, at least if you are on the same time zone as the epoch php is using (or whatever you timestamp is coming from). It would work at least for nothing too demanding of accuracy. PHP uses your system's time, so many things will break the idea (change the clock, DST, leap seconds, etc)

I would personally use timestamp - startofday timestamp and calculate using the language's calendar instead.

Comment: Ah this has actually helped me, specifically the last sentence, I wasn't aware you could do strtotime("midnight", $stamp) to get the midnight of the datestamp, which is exactly what I was after.